# Variac is blowing fuses

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

I'm using a variac to control voltage on a heating element and we're having issues with the fuse blowing. The variac is rated for a 10 amp fuse and we're using a 8 amp one. The 8 was suggested to avoid damaging our heating element. The max voltage we've used it at is 7.5 V, and with the element's resistance at 6.4 ohms, we calculate that it should be using less than 1 amp. Is the reason it's blowing because of an issue with our element or the setup, or is it because we're using a lower rated fuse?

Comment: Try measuring the current thru the heating element. Do you mind showing us a schematic of your setup?

Comment: Small nit: 7.5V into 6.4 ohms is slightly **more** than an amp, specifically 1.17 amps.

Comment: What kind of heating element are you using? Have you measured its resistance while it was cold or hot? Is your triac is functioning well?

Comment: It's a custom shaped heating element made with nickel chromium. We heat it to 750 C. Cold, we measure it at 6.4ohms, but we haven't measured it hot.

Comment: @JohnSnow Are you by any chance using DC current with variac?

Comment: @Golaz, I believe AC.

Comment: @JohnSnow You better be sure, variacs only work with AC, if you're applying DC then that's what is blowing your fuses.

Comment: If you're expecting ~1 amp, why is your fuse sized at 8 amps? And are you dropping 110 to 7.5 with the variac? And how do you know you're getting 7.5 when the fuse blows? Finally, are you taking the proper connection from the variac? If your load is connected the wrong way, you're getting 110 - 7.5, or more than 100 volts - which will surely blow your fuse.

Comment: We're using electricity from a wall and it's passing through a surge protector. I'm pretty sure that means it's AC? Is there a way I could test?

Comment: Measure it , How can you work on this sort of device if you don't have a suitable meter? As long as it is a surge protector and not a rectifier you should be good. However a photo might of help .. like determining the Variac is connected the correct way etc.

Answer (score 3):

Variacs can and do blow fuses.   I have seen this a few times.   The reason is transformer inrush current which is well documented in other articles.   All variacs that I have seen in CHCH NewZealand are of toroidal construction and are large.  These factors make inrush current worse.  If you don't want to up your fuse rating then you could try a slower fuse     OR you can use a relay and a NTC which does work.    This inrush problem has also occurred on high power Audio Amps using toroidal transformers.    I have used a relay and a 50HZ lamp ballast to cure this and allow reasonable fuse ratings.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Variac to get 7.5V AC from 115V AC that is not isolated from live mains seems a bit strange. Your load is only giving 8.7W of heat at this voltage but your Variac is rated for 1150W at full voltage.

I would instead suggest you use the Variac to give you 50V to 100V AC at 0.2A use that to feed a 115V to 12V transformer that is rated for 1 or 2 or 8 A on the secondary.  It will give you safety isolation and allow the use of a much smaller Variac if you want to make a bunch of these devices.  It will also allow you much finer control of the heat output as you would be working over a much larger angular range and still be getting close to your rated heating voltage.

I do suspect that you are not having a 8.7W heater and some of your numbers do not compute.

As mentioned you can only vary AC with a Variac.

There is a image of a variac wiring connection [here](http://www.afcaforum.com/attachment.php?id=48924).